# using wget to download website ignoring image and videos

Tags: wget

I'm new to wget and trying to download a full website ignoring any images on videos. What is the parameter? I tried going through wget --help but couldn't really find anything useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `man wget` is your best friend!

Answer (score 0):

The `-R` or `--reject` option is what you need here. See [the wget specs on gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files).

Say your URL is `http://somesite.org/`, then to download the root index and everything linked therefrom, ignoring media files, just do:

```
wget -r -R jpg,jpeg,gif,mpg,mkv http://somesite.org
```

where you add in whatever extra extensions the site is using for media files separated by commas.